# "Cannot unpack non-iterable float object" in system of odes inside a loop

Tags: python, loops, scipy, iterable, odeint

**Hi everyone, Im trying to solve a system of odes which describes a catalytic heterogeneous reaction for different temperatures. I'm trying to solve the same equations for different temperatures, using a function f, which is inside a for loop. Here's the code**

```
import scipy as sc
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np

T=np.array([100,200,300,400,500])
for y in T:
    def f(t,x,T):
        [FA,FB,FC,FD,FE,FF]=x
        e=2.711828
        R=8.314
        Tm=723.15
        A1=5.5
        A2=0.686
        A3=1.58
        A4=2.6
        A5=0.787
        E1=90500
        E2=165000
        E3=150000
        E4=139000
        E5=132000
        SB=-215
        HB=-45600
        SD=-42
        HD=-128000
        DH1=-105000
        DH2=-1428000
        DH3=-862000
        DH4=-1323000
        DH5=-757000
        k1=e**(A1-(E1/R)*((1/T)-(1/Tm)))
        k2=e**(A2-(E2/R)*((1/T)-(1/Tm)))
        k3=e**(A3-(E3/R)*((1/T)-(1/Tm)))
        k4=e**(A4-(E4/R)*((1/T)-(1/Tm)))
        k5=e**(A5-(E5/R)*((1/T)-(1/Tm)))
        KB=6.54e-12
        KD=1.19
        m2=0.922
        m3=0.906
        m4=1.23
        m5=0.905
        Patm=0.8*101325
        FT=178.47
        PA=(FA/FT)*Patm
        PB=(FB/FT)*Patm
        PC=(FC/FT)*Patm
        PD=(FD/FT)*Patm
        PE=(FE/FT)*Patm
        PF=(FF/FT)*Patm
        Tast=1/(1+((KB*PB)**0.5)+(KD*PD))
        TB=((KB*PB)**0.5)*Tast
        TD=KD*PD*Tast
        r1=(k1/1000)*TB*PA #mol
        r2=(k2/1000)*(TB**m2)*PA
        r3=(k3/1000)*(TB**m3)*PA
        r4=(k4/1000)*(TB**m4)*PC
        r5=(k5/1000)*(TB**m5)*PC
        rA=-r1-r2-r3
        rB=-r1-7*r2-5*r3-6*r4-4*r5
        rC=r1-r4-r5
        rD=r1+3*r2+3*r3+2*r4+2*r5
        rE=2*r2+2*r4
        rF=2*r3+2*r5
        FAdot=rA
        FBdot=rB
        FCdot=rC
        FDdot=rD
        FEdot=rE
        FFdot=rF
        return [FAdot,FBdot,FCdot,FDdot,FEdot,FFdot]
x0=(5,5,0,0,0,0)
soln=odeint(f,x0,(0,5),args=(T,))
print(soln)

However i get the following message
File "c:\Users\Axel Flores\Documents\Escuela\Proyectos\Python\import scipy as sc.py", line 7, in f
    [FA,FB,FC,FD,FE,FF]=x
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object
PS C:\Users\Axel Flores>
```

**Please help I know it is because the for loop but anything that I try provoques the same error. I've looked for solutions on the internet but none have worked.**

Comment: `f` isn't being called the way you think it is, such that `x` is a single float and not a list of length 6.

Comment: Check the docs.  The default argument order is `func(y, t, ...)`; either change your function definition to match, or use the `tfirst=True` option.  In general when you have problems with these `scipy` functions, reread the docs, and if necessary, add diagnositic print to your function to get a clear idea of what arguments it's getting.